# How to read persistent cookies stored by browser in java web start application

Tags: java, cookies, java-web-start

I have a java web start application. 
Before launching the application web page stores a persistent cookie.

This is have the cookie has created: (.asp page):

```
Response.Cookies("MyApp")("Test") = "SomeValue"
Response.Cookies("Myapp").Expires = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Now())
```

I can see the cookie inside chrome.

And this is how i tried to read the cookies:

```
CookieManager manager = new CookieManager();
manager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
CookieHandler.setDefault(manager);

CookieStore cookieJar = manager.getCookieStore();
List<HttpCookie> cookies = cookieJar.getCookies();
for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
    System.out.println("CookieHandler retrieved cookie: "
            + cookie);
}
```

How can i read that cookie in my application?

Comment: When you see the cookie inside Chrome, what is the domain, path and expiration?  Make sure that domain and path match what you expect. Also what happens if you run in another browser?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/accessingCookies.html) ? It has an example of Accessing Cookies from a java web start application.

Comment: Yes i have already tired it but. it does not retrieve the cookie.

Comment: Can you post code that you use to set the cookie, and the code used to retrieve the cookie.  If the examples by Oracle do not work, there may be something to fix in your code.